# "atualize-a" ou "atualizem-a" ou "atualizem-na" ou "atualizem a"?

Tags: ortografia, hífen

Fiquei com essa dúvida enquanto escrevia uma pergunta.

A frase original é:

> Seria melhor se as respostas sempre fossem marcadas como "community wiki", permitindo que mais pessoas **"atualizem" a resposta** para a respectiva "nacionalização"

Minha dúvida está aqui: "atualizem" a resposta para a respectiva

Qual seria o correto:

1. Seria melhor se as respostas... permitindo que ..."atualizem" a resposta para a respectiva...
2. Seria melhor se as respostas... permitindo que ..."atualizem-nas" para a respectiva...
3. Seria melhor se as respostas... permitindo que ..."atualizem-as" para a respectiva...
4. Seria melhor se as respostas... permitindo que ..."atualize-as" para a respectiva...

A primeira contém a palavra *resposta*, as outras três não.

Comment: Apagando_tudo, as coisas são um pouco mais complicadas. O autor não pode apagar a sua pergunta se esta tiver uma reposta com votos positivos, como é o caso desta [(vê aqui)](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions). Apagar  ou vandalizar o texto da pergunta é possível por enquanto. Mas quando isso aconteceu no passado, um moderador fez rollback e lock na pergunta. Eles têm o direito de fazer isso, porque ao postar texto no site nós cedemos à StackExchange o direito de usar esse texto como quiser [(vê Terms of Service, ponto 3)](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema na frase é que "as respostas" não se encontra no mesmo número. Opcionalmente a oração subordinada poderia manter o sujeito da oração principal. Eis a frase com as falhas identificadas a negrito:

> Seria melhor se **as respostas** sempre fossem marcadas como "community
>   wiki", permitindo que **mais pessoas** "atualizem" **a resposta** para a
>   respectiva "nacionalização"

O uso do [pronome oblíquo átono](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf44.php) é opcional. Segundo o artigo:

> Quando o verbo termina em som nasal, o pronome assume as formas no,
>   nos, na, nas.

Atualizem termina em som nasal e por isso deve ser usado "atualizem-nas"

Ainda assim, segundo o comentário do @Jacinto e suportado [pelo infoscola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/), a conjunção que obriga que pronome seja colocado antes do verbo (próclise)

> (2) Com conjunções subordinativas: quando, se, porque, que, conforme,
>   embora, logo, que.
>
> - Quando se trata de comida, ele é um “expert”.
> - É necessário que a deixe na escola.
> - Fazia a lista de convidados, conforme me lembrava dos amigos sinceros.

Por isso a frase correta seria, com o pronome:

> Seria melhor se as respostas sempre fossem marcadas como "community
>   wiki", permitindo que mais pessoas **as "atualizem"** para a
>   respectiva "nacionalização"

Sem o pronome:

> Seria melhor se as respostas sempre fossem marcadas como "community
>   wiki", permitindo que mais pessoas **"atualizem" as respostas** para a
>   respectiva "nacionalização"

Como sugeri anteriormente o sujeito poderia ser mantido:

> Seria melhor se as respostas sempre fossem marcadas como "community
>   wiki", permitindo que sejam atualizadas por mais pessoas
>   para a respectiva "nacionalização"

Comment: "permitindo **que** mais pessoas atulizem-nas" não é gramatical; a conjunção ***que*** pede a próclise.

Comment: @Jacinto Culpa da fonte que consultei, nao diz nada sobre o assunto. Vou corrigir apontando uma fonte que suporte a ideia.

Comment: Eu uso sempre a próclise em frases dessas, e soam-me estranhas com ênclise; mas fui ver ao Cunha e Cintra por descargo de consciência. Mas há milhentos de sites a explicar a colocação pronominal. Googla "colocação pronominal" e encontras logo uma meia dúzia.

Comment: O pessoa põe frequentemente arrobas dentro das respostas; mas aí isso não emite notificações.

Comment: @Jacinto eu sei disso. É só mesmo para dar crédito ao comentário.